# VBA code to insert blank rows doesn't always work

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to insert a blank row between 2 rows if the values in A1 <> A2.  I was given the code below and it works if the data looks like this `a,a,b,b,c,c,d,d,e,e,f,f,g,g,h,h,i,i`.  The results are exactly what I'm looking for: a, blank row, a, blank row, b blank row, b, blank row, c, blank row, c, etc.

However, if the data looks like this `a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i` then I get 8 blank rows between a and b but none anywhere else.

Any ideas why this is happening like this?

---

```
Sub Social_Distance()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lr As Long, MyUnion As Range, xCell As Range
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each xCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    If xCell.Value <> xCell.Offset(1).Value Then
        If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set MyUnion = Union(MyUnion, xCell.Offset(1))
        Else
            Set MyUnion = xCell.Offset(1)
        End If
    End If
Next xCell

If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then MyUnion.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

End Sub
```

Comment: Original post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747068/excel-vba-to-insert-blank-rows-is-taking-too-long/60747314?noredirect=1#comment107502610_60747314). I was not able to de-bug :(

Comment: This approach will not work when the data is singular, because VBA sees `Rows("1:2")` as a single range not two areas.  You will need to go with the other approach by using a helper column.

Comment: @ScottCraner that is disappointing. Sorry to waste your time Shaves

Comment: @urdearboy......no worries.....it was a learning experience; which is never a bad thing.  Thanks for your help.......

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this is what you need, It works well with different consecutive value cases:

**Note:** when two consecutive cells (in the same column) are added, it will be treated as one cell (this is how union works) so you will `get the Position of another cell in the same row but different column`, now the result: union = yellow range [see an image]

```
Sub Social_Distance()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim lr As Long, MyUnion As Range, xCell As Range
lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
k = 1
Dim cell As Range
For Each xCell In ws.Range("A2:A" & lr)
    If xCell.Value <> xCell.Offset(1).Value Then
        If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then
            Set MyUnion = Union(MyUnion, xCell.Offset(1, k)): k = k + 1 'increase column index
        Else
            Set MyUnion = xCell.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next xCell
If Not MyUnion Is Nothing Then MyUnion.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

[image]

For example:

[image]

Comment: This is great, as long as there are not more than 16384 breaks needed.  :)  I guess one can use `Mod` to start over if that was exceeded.  Or simply use `Mod 3` as long as the cells do not exist right below or right next to the other.

Comment: Hi, @ScottCraner: yes, that is quite possible ^^

Answer (score 1):

this uses a helper column and sorting to put in blank rows:

```
Sub Social_Distance()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet14")'change to your sheet

    Dim lr As Long
    lr = ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim rngArr As Variant
    rngArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), ws.Cells(lr, 1)).Value

    Dim rowArr() As Variant
    ReDim rowArr(1 To lr - 1, 1 To 1)

    Dim x As Double
    x = 0#

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 2 To lr
        If rngArr(i, 1) <> rngArr(i - 1, 1) Then x = x + 1
        rowArr(i - 1, 1) = x
    Next i

    Dim newLineArray() As Variant
    ReDim newLineArray(1 To Int(x - 1), 1 To 1)

    For i = 1 To Int(x - 1)
        newLineArray(i, 1) = CDbl(i) + 0.1
    Next i

    ws.Columns(1).Insert
    ws.Range("A1").Value = "Temp"
    ws.Range("A2").Resize(lr - 1).Value = rowArr
    ws.Range("A" & lr + 1).Resize(Int(x - 1)).Value = newLineArray

    ws.UsedRange.Sort key1:=ws.Range("A1"), Header:=xlYes

    ws.Columns(1).Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: @scottcramer.....thanks for all of the help.  I ended up using a couple of columns and adding blank rows at the bottom and then resorting.  It went from 12 minutes to 4 - 5 seconds.  Thanks again